# How to use React Hook "useSelector" outside of a React function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I split the routes into a routes.js file. Is there a way to use the "useSelector" hook to check isAdmin? React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

App.js

```js
import { router } from '~/routes/Routes';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

routes.js

```js
// can not use useSelector hook like this
const isAdmin = useSelector((state) => state.user.isAdmin);

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/admin',
    element: isAdmin ? <Admin /> : <Error />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
  },
]);
```

Comment: you can't. it's one of the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

Comment: In this context, you should add your admin check inside the `Admin` component, not routes.js

Comment: yes ☝ .. see the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)